# nodejs call generator function inside normal function

Tags: node.js, function, generator

I have  2 functions: one generator function and one normal one (without *). Generator function (example):

```
function* generator(i) {
  yield i;
  yield i + 10;
}
```

and normal function:

```
function normal(param) {
  var variable = 1;

  // yield generator function 
}
```

I know that it is impossible to yield inside normal function, but how can I call generator? Do I have to use Promises or smth similar? If it has to be Promise, then how it should look like? I tried to do it this way:

```
new Promise((resolve) => {
  var result = generator(3);

  Promise.all(result);
});
```

but this gives me an error

Also how it is working vice versa? For example if I need to call normal function inside generator?

Answer (score 2):

You use the `next()` method on the generator function like this:

```js
function* generator(i) {
  yield i;
  yield i + 10;
}

function higherLevel (){
  let gen = generator(1).next();
  return gen
}

console.log(higherLevel());
```

This way you can get the next value of `yield` inside another function.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `next` function from a GeneratorFunction to go to the next `yield` statement.

Take a look at the documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

```
function* generator(i) {
  yield i;
  yield i + 10;
}

const g = generator(10);
let result = g.next();
while (!result.done) {
    console.log(result.value)
    result = g.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print them all, it's easier to use the `await for` syntax as follows:

```
function * generator(i) {
  yield i;
  yield i + 10;
}

(async function printGenerator() {
  for await (const item of generator(3)) {
    console.log(item);
  }
})();
```

The output is

```
3
13
```